# good tool to quickly import some csv data into sql server

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

Every once in a while I find myself typing a one-off script to import some CSV data into a database, doing some column logic (e.g. turn column3 into uppercase) and/or field mapping (column2 in the csv goes to column 3 in de database, etc).

Is there a nice tool which can do this easier?

The least amount of features I'd need is:

- choosing delimiter
- Being able to map column X to column Y in the DB
- setting defaults for columns not in the csv file

SQL server management studio can almost do it, except one can not specify any defaults for values which are not listed in the csv file. So I'd then have to create extra columns in excel first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take a look at  [6 ways to import data into SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12) for some ideas, I think `SSIS` would be your best bet..but there is a learning curve. Or `BCP` into a staging table, massage the data there and then import intio the real table

Answer (score 5):

The definitive "best" tool for importing and exporting data to and from SQL Server is, in my opinion, the [BCP utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Do NOT be put off by the fact that there is no graphical user interface available to you. This tool exposes the widest range of functionality to the coder and also delivers the best performance of all SQL Server ETL Tools, fact.

Answer (score 3):

As you say you are looking for a tool to do this - we provide one I think you will find very interesting - as it will handle the default values as well as validation and upload to your chosen table and columns.

The tool will check the datatypes against the destination then validate the import by wrapping rows or the entire data within a transaction and report any problems against each row.

There is a post specifically relating to CSV import using the tool:
http://leansoftware.net/tabid/123/g/posts/t/17/Validate-and-Upload-CSV-file-to-a-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS) is the tool I typically use for such purposes. What's nice about a tool like this is that it's very fast, flexible and you can control batch sizes.

Answer (score 1):

right click on your database, go to Task > import Data
and follow the wizard to import data. It's a nice, easier way. Also look at following:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: I've mentioned this tool in my question. The drawback of this tool is that it doesn't allow of supplying defaults for columns which are in the DB but not in the CSV

Comment: I Agree, you can always update the table after import, or place default constraint to your columns will easily fix it.

Comment: Task->Import also does not handle quoted CSV, which is necessary for some US zipcodes, which can begin with a zero, or legacy general ledger codes which are often zero-padded.

Comment: I have never in 16 years, got this tool to work. It pretty much always comes up with some kind of error message which I'm never able to resolve.

Comment: @NickG, sad to know that! most of the time, it complains about data type used and data being truncated. I got it working after 2-3 attempts or sometimes more than that. I do agree that its tricky and don't provide too good error reporting to recover, I feel myself a little lucky to get it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new step-by-step guide available as regards using the EDT tool to import CSV data - focusing on various validation aspects:

http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/excel-database-tasks/worked-examples/how-to-import-csv-data-to-sql-server.aspx

Similarly to import Excel data:

http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/excel-database-tasks/worked-examples/how-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-to-sql-server-data.aspx

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I wrote [this](https://github.com/sirenum/csv2db) little python script that does exactly that (and a few more things). It basically parses csv files and writes sql insert statements. You can also create multiple related records in different tables from a single csv row. All you have to do is specify what goes where and how things are related.

An import specification for a 'department' table might look something like this:

```
DEPARTMENT_MAP = {
    '_oid':             DynamicValue(OidFactory()),                  # Compute _oid dynamically
    '_publicobj_oid':   XReference('publicobject', 'sole', '_oid'),  # Copy _oid value from 'sole' instance in 'publicobject' table
    'name':             ColumnValue('Department', convert=quote),    # Read from csv and put into quotes
    'building_no':      ConstValue('5')                              # Always 5
    'floor':            ColumnValue('Floor', convert=upper)          # Read from csv and convert to upper case
}
```